# Login Script in php to my MYSQL shows Deprecated warning

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing a simple program in php that requires users to login. I have a working code but whenever a wrong username or password is entered, I got an exception that says the following:

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\wamp\www\Directory\login.php on line 67

The script I have is working well, but I just need to get rid of this warning message. 
Below is my php code.

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

// Connect to the database
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

// Make sure we connected succesfully
if (!$con) {
    die('Connection Failed' . mysql_error());
}
// Select the database to use
mysql_select_db("Garden", $con);

$q = mysql_query("select * from register where username='" . $username . "'  and password='" . $password . "' ") or die(mysql_error());
$res = mysql_fetch_row($q);
if ($res) {
    header('location:home.php');
} else {
    echo 'Error. The Username or Password that you entered is invalid.';
}
?>
```

I dont know if im using something. This is my first time of using php. Please I need your help. Thank you.

Comment: Don't use a depreciated function then, use mysqli - http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php or PDO - http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the same code using MySQLi:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'db_name');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    printf("DB Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
// Add the UTF8 Support
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$mysqli->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
$username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($username);
$password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($password);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `register` WHERE username='" . $username . "' and password='" . $password . "' LIMIT 1";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
if(!empty($result)){
    if($result->num_rows == 1) {
        header("Location: home.php");
    } else {
        echo "Error. The Username or Password that you entered is invalid.";
    }
}
mysqli_close($mysqli);
$mysqli = null;
?>
```

You shouldn't be avoiding the PHP Errors. You should always fix the code accordingly.
You can use PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: @HarunaAdo I'm glad it worked :) Can you please mark this answer as valid so that others find the correct answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your code (small effort) using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) even if it's working properly and check if the message still appears.